# optionSplit repeats only first item in Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I tried using optionsplit with TMENU in TS, but it keeps repeating only first part, and I don't know why...

Here is TS:

```
temp.meni5col= HMENU
temp.meni5col.special = list
temp.meni5col.special.value = 5417, 5418, 5419, 5420, 5421
temp.meni5col.wrap= <div class="dropdown_5columns"><div class="col_1"><ul>|</ul></div></div>
temp.meni5col.1 = TMENU
temp.meni5col.1{
  expAll = 1
  NO {
    linkWrap = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>
  }
}
```

And here is HTML it generated:

```
<div class="dropdown_5columns">
                            <div class="col_1">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=5417">Servisi</a></li>
                                    <li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=5418">Usluge</a></li>
                                    <li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=5419">Dodatne usluge</a></li>
                                    <li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=5420">Tarifni modeli</a></li>
                                    <li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=5421">Ponuda uređaja</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I just realized optionSplit is not working. It shouldn't apply class="first" to all menu items.

Is there option in TYPO3 configuration for this function that needs to be enabled?
My TYPO3 version is 4.5.17.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the reason is that you use `linkWrap`. Try using `stdWrap`, `stdWrap2` or `wrapItemAndSub` instead, or one of the other wraps that have stdWrap-capabilities.

Comment: Also your TYPO3 Version is too old, please update to 4.5.29.

Comment: Yeah update your TYPO3

Answer (score 1):

It's because `linkWrap` is of data-type `wrap`. Use `stdWrap` to do an `optionSplit`.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html